# Play raw TX/RX bits as sound from a network interface?

Tags: linux, wifi, audio, internet

Alright, I know this is a weird one, but I want to hear the raw data being sent and received by my Wi-Fi card as sound data. I just find it interesting to hear data being sent as sound. The only true purpose it serves for me is to tell when my Wi-Fi card is transmitting data, and to provide a source of (somewhat) deterministic noise in my *very* silent office.

---

OS: Devuan Linux 5

Kernel: 5.10.0-17

WiFi card driver open source: yes

WiFi card: `ID 0bda:c820 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this would be a variation of this approach:

```
sudo tcpdump -w - -U | aplay -
```

It captures the packets from an ethernet interface, then feeds it into the default audio device. You might want to try various filters on `tcpdump` or different sample rates on `aplay`.

Sometimes it actually sounds interesting. Personally, I'd prefer silence.

Comment: @PeterSmith This worked perfectly! I used ffplay as opposed to aplay, however. Still works great!

Comment: @Foxy6670 ffmpeg gives a lot of options to chose from. I assume like `sudo tcpdump -w - -U | ffplay -f f64le -i -`.

Answer (score 2):

> The only true purpose it serves for me is to tell when my Wi-Fi card is transmitting data

So use that. Under `/sys/class/net/<interface name>/statistics/` there are various counters, use e.g. `rx_bytes` and `tx_bytes`. Write a small program that reads the counters in a fixed interval, calculates the delta, and translates the delta in some kind of sound, e.g. noise modulated by the amount of bytes currently transmitted. You modulate volume or other parameters of the noise.

Comment: Nice! Your answer saved me looking up the path for my answer :) (which I hope you like as well. Would be nice if you could check it!)

Answer (score 1):

> The only true purpose it serves for me is to tell when my Wi-Fi card is transmitting data, and to provide a source of (somewhat) deterministic noise in my very silent office.

I went a bit overboard in the comments explaining why you can't hear "raw" data.

But what you really want is what phone communication engineers call *comfort noise* enriched with some kinda changing data.

So, build that! **This is meant to be a small introduction on how to build such things.** You can just follow and copy&paste along, or you can try to understand every step in depth – whatever excites you more :)

## A Small Tutorial on How To Build Signal Generation Applications

### Comfort Noise and GNU Radio Companion First Steps

Let's start with the comfort noise part. It's easy to install GNU Radio (run `apt install gnuradio`). Then open the GNU Radio Companion.

You'll want to read the official tutorials on https://tutorials.gnuradio.org, but for now, just use the search bar on the right to find two blocks:

1. Audio Sink
2. Noise Source

Add them to the canvas, and connect them. Double-click on the Noise Source block, and change its output type to "float".

Result should look like this:

[image: Noise Source -> Audio Sink]

Change the samp_rate variable block the same way to have the value 48000. Hit the "Execute" button. (Depends on your desktop environment, but typically looks like ⏵; you can also find it in the "Run" menu as "Execute".)

[image: 48000 sampling rate]

Congratulations, white noise coming out of your speakers! You can adjust the volume, as well, by setting the "Amplitude" of the noise source (Try 0.1 instead of 1).

### Shaping the Noise and a Bit of Filtering

That's cool. Let's make the noise a bit less annoying, by finding the Low-Pass Filter block, removing the direct connection between Noise Source and Audio Sink and instead placing the filter in between them. Set the filter to be "Float -> Float (Decimating)", and set its cutoff frequency to be 3000, with a transition width of 1500. Now you have converted your white noise to more human-friendly low-pass noise, *colored noise*. Try it!

[image: Noise Source -> Low Pass Filter -> Audio Sink]

### How We're Going to Get Data Rate Into Our System

Now, we'll have to somehow add the traffic information into this whole system.

You can do that by periodically asking Linux how many bytes have passed through the network interface, and calculating the difference to the last time you asked - that way, you get a data rate, simply a number. If that number is high, we want our noise to be louder, or some tone to be higher or... Basically, we could think of this as done electronic music artist sitting in front of their large modular synthesizer and turning knobs, any knob we want, for us, in dependence on the data rate.

So, small problem: unlike the Audio Sink and the Noise Sources, GNU Radio doesn't already come with a block that does the calculation of the data rate. That's not a problem, we can build that ourselves.

#### But How Does it Work?

Small step back. What happened when you clicked the "Execute" button? The GNU Radio companion went, looked at the *Flow Graph* you've built, and generates a Python program out of that.

This program instantiates all the blocks you've added, configures them, tells the GNU Radio runtime how they are connected. Then, the program tells the runtime to actually start hauling the data through the flow graph, which means it tells the Noise Source to produce a few noise samples, and as these are then ready, tells the Filter to filter them, and as that is done, tells the Audio Sink to hand the filtered samples off to the sound card. (In fact, in the meantime, the Noise Source has already started to produce more samples, everything runs in parallel.)

So, it's all small parts of software that generate, transform, or finally handle numbers exchanged between the block "upstream" a connection and their input, and between their output and a block "downstream".

### Development Task at Hand

#### What We Want in the End

So, our job will be to write a small piece of software that does the same. We'll just plug it in after the filter. This is how I envisioned it would look like: (this is a mockup!)

[image: Mockup of how it should look like]

It's a block that copies input to output, multiplying it with rate of change of some integer that gets read from a file.

So, the first argument would be the name of the file to read, I use `"/sys/class/net/wlp0s20u11/statistics/tx_bytes"` here – replace `wlp0s20u11` with the device name of your wifi card (if in doubt, ask `ip link` or `nmcli device`).

The second argument would be the number of input samples after which the file gets read again, so that we get a continuous update.

#### Building It

So, I coded that. You can do the same! Find the "Embedded Python Block" block and add it to your flowgraph. Double click on it to open its properties, there click on "Open in Editor", and copy and paste exactly this code (whitespace is important!):

```py
import numpy as np
from gnuradio import gr


class blk(gr.sync_block):
    """
    Multiply by difference read from file

    This block reads an integer from a text file, after every configurable
    interval of input has been processed, calculates the per-sample rate at
    which that integer changed since the last read, and multiplies the input
    with that rate to calculate the output.

    Parameters:
     - filename                  The file to read periodically
     - read_every_n_samples      After how many samples to re-read to
                                 calculate the per-sample rate
     - max_increment_per_sample  The maximum rate to which we normalize
                                 our current rate. Set to 0 to not normalize.
    """
    def __init__(self,
                 filename="/sys/class/net/wlp0s20u11/statistics/tx_bytes",
                 read_every_n_samples=1000,
                 max_increment_per_sample=0):
        gr.sync_block.__init__(
            self,
            name='Multiply by difference from file',  # will show up in GRC
            in_sig=[np.float32],
            out_sig=[np.float32])
        self.interval = int(read_every_n_samples)
        self.next_read_in = self.interval
        self.filename = filename
        self.factor = 1
        self.max_increment_per_sample = max_increment_per_sample

    def read_value(self):
        with open(self.filename, "r", encoding="ascii") as file_handle:
            line_string = file_handle.readline()
            return int(line_string)

    def start(self):
        self.last_value = self.read_value()

    def work(self, input_items, output_items):
        in_stream = input_items[0]
        output = output_items[0]

        if self.next_read_in == 0:
            # We've reached the point at which we need
            # to update the factor with which we multiply!
            # So let's do that:
            new_value = self.read_value()
            difference = new_value - self.last_value
            rate = difference / self.interval
            if self.max_increment_per_sample > 0:
                rate = rate / self.max_increment_per_sample
                rate = min(1, max(rate, 0))
            self.factor = rate
            self.last_value = new_value
            self.next_read_in = self.interval

        # number of samples to which apply the same factor
        # This is at most as many items we currently have available at
        # the input, or as many items are left in this update period
        # (whatever is less)
        n_to_process = min(len(in_stream), self.next_read_in)

        # from current offset, the next n_to_process
        # input values get multiplied with the same factor
        # and written to the output
        output[:n_to_process] = in_stream[:n_to_process] * self.factor
        # We've consumed n_to_process input items, so we advance our
        # offset and reduce the amount of outstanding input
        self.next_read_in -= n_to_process

        # We consumed and produced n
        return n_to_process
```

Save and close your editor.

The properties dialog should now look like this:

[image: Properties Dialog]

As, said, you'll have to replace `wlp…` by the actual device name of your wifi card. We update 4 times per second (and since we do samp_rate samples per second, that means once ever samp_rate/4 samples). And I set the maximum rate per second I'm expecting averaged over that period to be 5·10⁶ bytes/s, so 5·10⁶/samp_rate.

### Conclusion

And we've just converted our mockup of what should happen to something that actually makes noise in accordance to the amount of bytes going out to your card. I've not only written it, I've tried it! It works. While I'm not doing anything, there's mostly silence, but an occasional packet from some chat program that I'm still there, or my email client checking in, but as soon as I cause some outbound data, I can hear the pulsation of packets.

So, if you know a bit of Python (not too much, honestly), and feel like reading the tutorials and my source code above, you'll be able to rightfully claim you've built a real-time signal processing system for monitoring network state acoustically. That's actually not too bad a feat, and it only took asking a question on here :)

Of course, this is far from perfect. You might want to modify the python code I gave you – probably, taking the logarithm of the rate would be a good idea. So would probably also be being cleverer about interpolating the rate (instead of just holding the last rate). If you feel like writing a bit of Python, I think this might be a good starting point. There's also no reason you need to feed in noise – instead of the Noise Source and the filter, you might just as well use a "Wav File Source" (that can read most compressed audio formats like Ogg vorbis, OPUS, MP4 AAC…, not only WAV files) to play your favourite music.

Or, you could use GNU Radio and a small radio receiver (so-called "RTL-SDR Dongle") with an appropriate antenna to actually receive your local radio station, and use that as basis signal instead of the noise. The options are quite varied! GNU Radio is a signal processing framework that's been created for these kinds of situations, where you need to process a stream of digital signal, be it audio, or radio signals, or something else altogether, in real time.

Comment: This is awesome. I joined this group so I could upvote; why aren’t there 20 more?

Comment: @DanBoschen I might have gotten carried away with this one :)